# “Had he not stamped on that money”?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, inversion

[Source](https://books.google.jo/books?id=N3FRBAQgcxEC&pg=PT327&dq=had%20he%20stamped%20on%20money%20karmasov&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA09Lu2Y7YAhWP2aQKHeShDO8Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=had%20he%20stamped%20on%20money%20karmasov&f=false)

> - Because, Lise, **had** he not stamped on that money, but taken it instead, then, on arriving home, after an hour or so he would have started to weep over his...

What is the kind of this “had”?

Is it an inversion for emphasizing?

Or the causative one? If it is causative, where is the person or thing that causes stamped on that money? Because **Lise** is separated by a comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express the idea of an *if*-clause by putting **had** at the initial position.

> Had I studied for the exam, I would have passed.
>
> If I had studied for the exam, I would have passed.

It is a variant conditional construction.

> ... **had** he not stamped on that money but taken it instead ... he
>   **would** have started to weep

Lise is being addressed. Consider:

> Because, *my good fellow*, you and I will have an opportunity to
>   discuss this matter in great detail at tomorrow's meeting, I will not
>   go into it further right now.

Comment: Thank U. I got it. This condition is if-clause without using “if”. In your example, the **meant** good fellow is just you without I, isn’t it?

Comment: "my good fellow" is a term of address; it refers to the person being spoken to.   "Bavyan, my good fellow, since you are going to New York on Thursday, could you stop in at the museum and say hello to Mr Jones?"